# Remove escape character before quotes in array of JSON strings PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array of JSON strings in a PHP array. I would like to convert this array to a JavaScript array so I can treat each array index as an Object and access its information.

The problem I am having is that when I perform the json_encode function to the array to make it readable for JS, it is adding backslashes before "" quotation markers, making it an invalid JSON.

I tried using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES but it doesnt remove the backslash before the quotes.

```
    <?php

$markerArray = getMarkers();
$allMarkers = array();

for($x=0; $x<sizeof($markerArray); $x++)
{
    array_push($allMarkers,$markerArray[$x]['json']);
}

$allMarkersJson = json_encode($allMarkers, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
     ?>

<script>

var allMarkers = <?php echo $allMarkersJson ?>;

    </script>
```

The thing I find strange is that if I do:

```
console.log(allMarkers[0]);
```

the console will display a valid JSON formatted string, however when I try to access the JSON's information using something like this:

```
var firstLocation = allMarkers[0].geometry.location //this line doesnt work
```

I looked at the source on the webpage, my JSON string array looks like this:

```
var allMarkers = ["{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"London\",\"short_name\":\"London\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"London\",\"short_name\":\"London\",\"types\":[\"postal_town\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Greater London\",\"short_name\":\"Greater London\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"England\",\"short_name\":\"England\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United Kingdom\",\"short_name\":\"GB\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"locality\\\">London</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">UK</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"London, UK\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":51.5073509,\"lng\":-0.12775829999998223},\"viewport\":{\"south\":51.38494009999999,\"west\":-0.351468299999965,\"north\":51.6723432,\"east\":0.14827100000002247}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0\",\"name\":\"London\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":800,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100576107799945331393/photos\\\">Edu Sousa</a>\"],\"width\":1200},{\"height\":1065,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117641363844967821087/photos\\\">Manuel Ligabue</a>\"],\"width\":1600},{\"height\":1365,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107957051173910448327/photos\\\">David Sun</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":2136,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110744511144480687702/photos\\\">Nuno Martins</a>\"],\"width\":3216},{\"height\":3000,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118133211030153942640/photos\\\">Roberto Gerosa</a>\"],\"width\":4000},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102674303425902835965/photos\\\">ALLWYN D&#39;SILVA</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111050241231844820150/photos\\\">Cristina Cunsolo</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1362,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101001561862058426912/photos\\\">Dendy Legends</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":1440,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111849553513496073867/photos\\\">Destiny Symonee</a>\"],\"width\":2560},{\"height\":1452,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109648577636572315039/photos\\\">Leslie</a>\"],\"width\":5248}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAECyOPILuxB_45ounoXLy4387nU1sL4SAn_6TIJ0GjpK13g4RTdUz9HI743oHwEAmUc0mwviYFsDTl8fPwU7bPmH5dF0GzCgfXZ0JgHfdsJpBURT3KzfThODOtvpCEwKvEhCZ0E7NhwOHEdRTchmzTVU2GhQwQVlOeJNU8lKjQ7IzuVtIsHTX0Q\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=London,+UK&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99\",\"utc_offset\":60,\"vicinity\":\"London\",\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Colombia\",\"short_name\":\"CO\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"country-name\\\">Colombia</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Colombia\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":4.570868,\"lng\":-74.29733299999998},\"viewport\":{\"south\":-4.227109899999999,\"west\":-81.83170000000001,\"north\":13.5177999,\"east\":-66.8463122}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"e29a4032ff2887a4fff7cbf2180e93f9daa507bf\",\"name\":\"Colombia\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":3456,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115948812578724412678/photos\\\">MARCO ANTONIO OLAYO PELAEZ</a>\"],\"width\":4608},{\"height\":678,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111915823344085556098/photos\\\">Pkaosv Patricia</a>\"],\"width\":1024},{\"height\":1200,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":960,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116104116331250803004/photos\\\">SALVATORE PATACCA</a>\"],\"width\":1280},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1655,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104824757791951382120/photos\\\">\u0422\u0430\u043d\u044f \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0430</a>\"],\"width\":1500},{\"height\":854,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114155114598408331784/photos\\\">Miqael Sareyan</a>\"],\"width\":960},{\"height\":640,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108925849575879291804/photos\\\">Raul Romero</a>\"],\"width\":640},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":2988,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102850832400486673235/photos\\\">Jose M\u00e1rsico</a>\"],\"width\":5312}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJo5QVrjqkFY4RQKPy7wSaDZo\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAtNufd19nymzOF3zAg2DimiVwWqNUy-WPS4hh-1JEs4lU34ZwF5I6UtmGkg36__jSjItC5E7h6ibCZpFI6vdSU3pEnfC3m2V2eZclRQXODXkntdyFYkhjhetuvmJGXP4REhD3okVDytIbifqJmyN9CKfJGhTOnZfVWE8TOtY7H4b8RDmfYGJqFQ\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Colombia&ftid=0x8e15a43aae1594a3:0x9a0d9a04eff2a340\",\"utc_offset\":-300,\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Long Island City\",\"short_name\":\"LIC\",\"types\":[\"neighborhood\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Queens\",\"short_name\":\"Queens\",\"types\":[\"sublocality_level_1\",\"sublocality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Queens County\",\"short_name\":\"Queens County\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"New York\",\"short_name\":\"NY\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United States\",\"short_name\":\"US\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"Long Island City, <span class=\\\"locality\\\">Queens</span>, <span class=\\\"region\\\">NY</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">USA</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Long Island City, Queens, NY, USA\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":40.74467899999999,\"lng\":-73.94854240000001},\"viewport\":{\"south\":40.727849,\"west\":-73.96285769999997,\"north\":40.7630563,\"east\":-73.9094829}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"85c47d41ef2535488f5d668693469ede878baf29\",\"name\":\"Long Island City\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":1536,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106648548916038105849/photos\\\">Josh Ross</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102709536865894032163/photos\\\">clinton urling</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1799,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111704576310722856902/photos\\\">pietro cefali</a>\"],\"width\":1799},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107345525537239890276/photos\\\">Stephen Kim</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1802,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115669779561965803211/photos\\\">Kin Tsui</a>\"],\"width\":3200},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105582811460978979717/photos\\\">Eve Lenti</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":4032,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114125059648511830046/photos\\\">Tom Moncho</a>\"],\"width\":3024},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105582811460978979717/photos\\\">Eve Lenti</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":1802,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115669779561965803211/photos\\\">Kin Tsui</a>\"],\"width\":3200},{\"height\":3672,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117979751334919367476/photos\\\">Alexander Mejia</a>\"],\"width\":4896}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJWbG6xytZwokRMY7uxcRsFVY\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAzXeKS-MA7GR_9zEN7wJtoqiosZLpw8np1FOCmL_HlyDCrrlup6zJIJLxB1PAa4Mnz_qIlH4VHr8uOxmuLJcdV2Zokcwapzdp0avjBxHEVJtBf4qTFd7T9ljKwozod2GZEhBx_WfeW_ORecNj-i18JC-zGhQ8Mdwgic0AgUpHjteggBysYYyjXg\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"neighborhood\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Long+Island+City,+Queens,+NY,+USA&ftid=0x89c2592bc7bab159:0x56156cc4c5ee8e31\",\"utc_offset\":-240,\"vicinity\":\"Queens\",\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Longmont\",\"short_name\":\"Longmont\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Boulder County\",\"short_name\":\"Boulder County\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Colorado\",\"short_name\":\"CO\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United States\",\"short_name\":\"US\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"locality\\\">Longmont</span>, <span class=\\\"region\\\">CO</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">USA</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Longmont, CO, USA\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":40.1672068,\"lng\":-105.10192749999999},\"viewport\":{\"south\":40.12596,\"west\":-105.17838699999999,\"north\":40.209958,\"east\":-105.01732190000001}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"7be664ab48acee2490a7e9dff9990deb9f6ece7a\",\"name\":\"Longmont\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":1066,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1599},{\"height\":2176,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117621644782905861513/photos\\\">w citta</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":2176,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117621644782905861513/photos\\\">w citta</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":1599,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066},{\"height\":1836,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116504687303728917803/photos\\\">Robert Gipson</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":1836,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116504687303728917803/photos\\\">Robert Gipson</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105943357466694902459/photos\\\">Rosita Lyons</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":1600,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104220518301745623090/photos\\\">Rick</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1600,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJSTPM1Qj5a4cRNSej8-6hfcE\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAA9RKgFD_klpF5XyMfPUMsVH24Pnyi1OAuoJbtVpdYdiUX7uFL3ONxwkxDoaAxDn3tbn-5sUS6jZl82SnzcUK6wbIU_ut3-MkR-RMxgkNv7BEzzdZ54vHSnx0hX6WmuDsPEhC_Q2UGgBzb0MhJacHPhfaOGhTYVde7sdBmzy8gi1Eg_UqjageYGQ\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Longmont,+CO,+USA&ftid=0x876bf908d5cc3349:0xc17da1eef3a32735\",\"utc_offset\":-360,\"vicinity\":\"Longmont\",\"html_attributions\":[]}"];
```

However when I console.log an index of the Array, it removes the backslashes:

```
var firstIndex = allMarkers[0];
console.log(firstIndex);

//produces:

{"address_components":[{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"London","short_name":"London","types":["postal_town"]},{"long_name":"Greater London","short_name":"Greater London","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"England","short_name":"England","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United Kingdom","short_name":"GB","types":["country","political"]}],"adr_address":"<span class=\"locality\">London</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">UK</span>","formatted_address":"London, UK","geometry":{"location":{"lat":51.5073509,"lng":-0.12775829999998223},"viewport":{"south":51.38494009999999,"west":-0.351468299999965,"north":51.6723432,"east":0.14827100000002247}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png","id":"b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0","name":"London","photos":[{"height":800,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100576107799945331393/photos\">Edu Sousa</a>"],"width":1200},{"height":1065,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117641363844967821087/photos\">Manuel Ligabue</a>"],"width":1600},{"height":1365,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107957051173910448327/photos\">David Sun</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":2136,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110744511144480687702/photos\">Nuno Martins</a>"],"width":3216},{"height":3000,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118133211030153942640/photos\">Roberto Gerosa</a>"],"width":4000},{"height":3024,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102674303425902835965/photos\">ALLWYN D&#39;SILVA</a>"],"width":4032},{"height":1080,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111050241231844820150/photos\">Cristina Cunsolo</a>"],"width":1920},{"height":1362,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101001561862058426912/photos\">Dendy Legends</a>"],"width":2048},{"height":1440,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111849553513496073867/photos\">Destiny Symonee</a>"],"width":2560},{"height":1452,"html_attributions":["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109648577636572315039/photos\">Leslie</a>"],"width":5248}],"place_id":"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI","reference":"CmRbAAAAECyOPILuxB_45ounoXLy4387nU1sL4SAn_6TIJ0GjpK13g4RTdUz9HI743oHwEAmUc0mwviYFsDTl8fPwU7bPmH5dF0GzCgfXZ0JgHfdsJpBURT3KzfThODOtvpCEwKvEhCZ0E7NhwOHEdRTchmzTVU2GhQwQVlOeJNU8lKjQ7IzuVtIsHTX0Q","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["locality","political"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=London,+UK&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99","utc_offset":60,"vicinity":"London","html_attributions":[]}
```

Comment: What it looks like to me, is you have `$markerArray[$x]['json']` ... which in itself may be where it is escaping quotes incorrectly. Check the actual variable content of that array you are building from. Because if you json_encode a json string, it will screw with it like this.

Comment: If you can't find where the slashes are added, then `$allMarkersJson = stripslashes($allMarkersJson);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
  var allMarkers = ["{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"London\",\"short_name\":\"London\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"London\",\"short_name\":\"London\",\"types\":[\"postal_town\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Greater London\",\"short_name\":\"Greater London\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"England\",\"short_name\":\"England\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United Kingdom\",\"short_name\":\"GB\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"locality\\\">London</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">UK</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"London, UK\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":51.5073509,\"lng\":-0.12775829999998223},\"viewport\":{\"south\":51.38494009999999,\"west\":-0.351468299999965,\"north\":51.6723432,\"east\":0.14827100000002247}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"b1a8b96daab5065cf4a08f953e577c34cdf769c0\",\"name\":\"London\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":800,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100576107799945331393/photos\\\">Edu Sousa</a>\"],\"width\":1200},{\"height\":1065,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117641363844967821087/photos\\\">Manuel Ligabue</a>\"],\"width\":1600},{\"height\":1365,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107957051173910448327/photos\\\">David Sun</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":2136,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110744511144480687702/photos\\\">Nuno Martins</a>\"],\"width\":3216},{\"height\":3000,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118133211030153942640/photos\\\">Roberto Gerosa</a>\"],\"width\":4000},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102674303425902835965/photos\\\">ALLWYN D&#39;SILVA</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111050241231844820150/photos\\\">Cristina Cunsolo</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1362,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101001561862058426912/photos\\\">Dendy Legends</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":1440,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111849553513496073867/photos\\\">Destiny Symonee</a>\"],\"width\":2560},{\"height\":1452,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109648577636572315039/photos\\\">Leslie</a>\"],\"width\":5248}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAECyOPILuxB_45ounoXLy4387nU1sL4SAn_6TIJ0GjpK13g4RTdUz9HI743oHwEAmUc0mwviYFsDTl8fPwU7bPmH5dF0GzCgfXZ0JgHfdsJpBURT3KzfThODOtvpCEwKvEhCZ0E7NhwOHEdRTchmzTVU2GhQwQVlOeJNU8lKjQ7IzuVtIsHTX0Q\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=London,+UK&ftid=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99\",\"utc_offset\":60,\"vicinity\":\"London\",\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Colombia\",\"short_name\":\"CO\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"country-name\\\">Colombia</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Colombia\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":4.570868,\"lng\":-74.29733299999998},\"viewport\":{\"south\":-4.227109899999999,\"west\":-81.83170000000001,\"north\":13.5177999,\"east\":-66.8463122}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"e29a4032ff2887a4fff7cbf2180e93f9daa507bf\",\"name\":\"Colombia\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":3456,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115948812578724412678/photos\\\">MARCO ANTONIO OLAYO PELAEZ</a>\"],\"width\":4608},{\"height\":678,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111915823344085556098/photos\\\">Pkaosv Patricia</a>\"],\"width\":1024},{\"height\":1200,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":960,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116104116331250803004/photos\\\">SALVATORE PATACCA</a>\"],\"width\":1280},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1655,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104824757791951382120/photos\\\">\u0422\u0430\u043d\u044f \u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0430</a>\"],\"width\":1500},{\"height\":854,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114155114598408331784/photos\\\">Miqael Sareyan</a>\"],\"width\":960},{\"height\":640,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108925849575879291804/photos\\\">Raul Romero</a>\"],\"width\":640},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102790316549178746882/photos\\\">Bhairob Burman</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":2988,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102850832400486673235/photos\\\">Jose M\u00e1rsico</a>\"],\"width\":5312}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJo5QVrjqkFY4RQKPy7wSaDZo\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAtNufd19nymzOF3zAg2DimiVwWqNUy-WPS4hh-1JEs4lU34ZwF5I6UtmGkg36__jSjItC5E7h6ibCZpFI6vdSU3pEnfC3m2V2eZclRQXODXkntdyFYkhjhetuvmJGXP4REhD3okVDytIbifqJmyN9CKfJGhTOnZfVWE8TOtY7H4b8RDmfYGJqFQ\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Colombia&ftid=0x8e15a43aae1594a3:0x9a0d9a04eff2a340\",\"utc_offset\":-300,\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Long Island City\",\"short_name\":\"LIC\",\"types\":[\"neighborhood\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Queens\",\"short_name\":\"Queens\",\"types\":[\"sublocality_level_1\",\"sublocality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Queens County\",\"short_name\":\"Queens County\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"New York\",\"short_name\":\"NY\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United States\",\"short_name\":\"US\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"Long Island City, <span class=\\\"locality\\\">Queens</span>, <span class=\\\"region\\\">NY</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">USA</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Long Island City, Queens, NY, USA\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":40.74467899999999,\"lng\":-73.94854240000001},\"viewport\":{\"south\":40.727849,\"west\":-73.96285769999997,\"north\":40.7630563,\"east\":-73.9094829}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"85c47d41ef2535488f5d668693469ede878baf29\",\"name\":\"Long Island City\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":1536,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106648548916038105849/photos\\\">Josh Ross</a>\"],\"width\":2048},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102709536865894032163/photos\\\">clinton urling</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1799,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111704576310722856902/photos\\\">pietro cefali</a>\"],\"width\":1799},{\"height\":3024,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107345525537239890276/photos\\\">Stephen Kim</a>\"],\"width\":4032},{\"height\":1802,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115669779561965803211/photos\\\">Kin Tsui</a>\"],\"width\":3200},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105582811460978979717/photos\\\">Eve Lenti</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":4032,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114125059648511830046/photos\\\">Tom Moncho</a>\"],\"width\":3024},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105582811460978979717/photos\\\">Eve Lenti</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":1802,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115669779561965803211/photos\\\">Kin Tsui</a>\"],\"width\":3200},{\"height\":3672,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117979751334919367476/photos\\\">Alexander Mejia</a>\"],\"width\":4896}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJWbG6xytZwokRMY7uxcRsFVY\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAAzXeKS-MA7GR_9zEN7wJtoqiosZLpw8np1FOCmL_HlyDCrrlup6zJIJLxB1PAa4Mnz_qIlH4VHr8uOxmuLJcdV2Zokcwapzdp0avjBxHEVJtBf4qTFd7T9ljKwozod2GZEhBx_WfeW_ORecNj-i18JC-zGhQ8Mdwgic0AgUpHjteggBysYYyjXg\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"neighborhood\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Long+Island+City,+Queens,+NY,+USA&ftid=0x89c2592bc7bab159:0x56156cc4c5ee8e31\",\"utc_offset\":-240,\"vicinity\":\"Queens\",\"html_attributions\":[]}","{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Longmont\",\"short_name\":\"Longmont\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Boulder County\",\"short_name\":\"Boulder County\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"Colorado\",\"short_name\":\"CO\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"]},{\"long_name\":\"United States\",\"short_name\":\"US\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"]}],\"adr_address\":\"<span class=\\\"locality\\\">Longmont</span>, <span class=\\\"region\\\">CO</span>, <span class=\\\"country-name\\\">USA</span>\",\"formatted_address\":\"Longmont, CO, USA\",\"geometry\":{\"location\":{\"lat\":40.1672068,\"lng\":-105.10192749999999},\"viewport\":{\"south\":40.12596,\"west\":-105.17838699999999,\"north\":40.209958,\"east\":-105.01732190000001}},\"icon\":\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png\",\"id\":\"7be664ab48acee2490a7e9dff9990deb9f6ece7a\",\"name\":\"Longmont\",\"photos\":[{\"height\":1066,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1599},{\"height\":2176,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117621644782905861513/photos\\\">w citta</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":2176,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117621644782905861513/photos\\\">w citta</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":1599,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066},{\"height\":1836,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116504687303728917803/photos\\\">Robert Gipson</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":1836,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116504687303728917803/photos\\\">Robert Gipson</a>\"],\"width\":3264},{\"height\":3264,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105943357466694902459/photos\\\">Rosita Lyons</a>\"],\"width\":1836},{\"height\":1600,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066},{\"height\":1080,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104220518301745623090/photos\\\">Rick</a>\"],\"width\":1920},{\"height\":1600,\"html_attributions\":[\"<a href=\\\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106803677370782471035/photos\\\">shanachie carroll</a>\"],\"width\":1066}],\"place_id\":\"ChIJSTPM1Qj5a4cRNSej8-6hfcE\",\"reference\":\"CmRbAAAA9RKgFD_klpF5XyMfPUMsVH24Pnyi1OAuoJbtVpdYdiUX7uFL3ONxwkxDoaAxDn3tbn-5sUS6jZl82SnzcUK6wbIU_ut3-MkR-RMxgkNv7BEzzdZ54vHSnx0hX6WmuDsPEhC_Q2UGgBzb0MhJacHPhfaOGhTYVde7sdBmzy8gi1Eg_UqjageYGQ\",\"scope\":\"GOOGLE\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"],\"url\":\"https://maps.google.com/?q=Longmont,+CO,+USA&ftid=0x876bf908d5cc3349:0xc17da1eef3a32735\",\"utc_offset\":-360,\"vicinity\":\"Longmont\",\"html_attributions\":[]}"]


  var map = allMarkers.map(function(e) {
   return JSON.parse(e);
  });

  console.log(map);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! So this mapping function is parsing each string in the array individually?

Comment: yes ... the MAP function allows you to create an object in a custom way. Here you find some way to use. https://www.javascripture.com/Map

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the `allMarkers` has the `["` and `"]` wrapping the JSON.  This means it is treating the contents as an ARRAY with a SINGLE STRING inside of it.  That string is an escaped JSON string.

That is why when you do this:

```
var firstIndex = allMarkers[0];
console.log(firstIndex);
```

You get it without the slashes: it's grabbing the first element (that's the `[0]` bit) and then printing it as a string, NOT as a JSON object.

Try just changing

```
$allMarkersJson = json_encode($allMarkers, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

to

```
$allMarkersJson = json_encode($allMarkers);
```

If you're trying to keep the array concept, then using single quotes instead might work, but **without visibility into the `getMarkers` function so we can see what this value gives, we cannot be sure: `$markerArray[$x]['json']`**